# On obtaining the standard boundary condition for the radial equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, boundary-conditions

The solution of spherically-symmetric one-particle problems is often facilitated by looking for solutions of the form
$$\psi(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$$
where of course the $Y_l^m$ are the spherical harmonics and $R$ is some radial function which obeys a standard radial equation that emerges from the full eigenvalue equation. At any rate, one usually writes $R(r) = u(r)/r$ for some function $u$, which I can accept remains completely general. However, it is subsequently mentioned that one must insist (i.e. so that the solution is physically realizable -- a more stringent restriction than being in the extended space, $\Omega^\times$, of the rigged-Hilbert-space triplet) that acceptable $u$ are those $u$ which obey the boundary condition $u(0) = 0$. **Why is this?**

Ballentine (Quantum Mechanics: a Modern Development, Chap 10.1 of the 2nd edition) says "since $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$ would otherwise have an $r^{-1}$ singularity at the origin. It was argued in Sec. 4.5 that such a singularity is unacceptable." The argument which he is alluding to (I attach it at the end) in his Sec. 4.5 seems to require that $u(r)/r^\alpha$ have $\alpha < 1$ *if* $u$ is complex-valued and *if* the integral noted by Ballentine does not vanish. *If* these conditions hold for the given $u$, then $\alpha < 1$ would apply and so we could conclude that $u(r)/r$ is not physically realizable. But who is to say these conditions need hold for arbitrary $u$? And so if we have $u$ which is, for example, real-valued (thereby violating one of Ballentine's conditions), then only Ballentine's $\alpha<3/2$ condition applies, to which $u(r)/r$ is acceptable after all...

**Am I misunderstanding Ballentine's argument, or is this an error in logic?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does $\nabla \Psi $ itself need to approach a  well-defined limit at the origin in this formalism? If so, I think you can argue that you must have $\alpha < 1$ in this language; consider the limit $x\to 0$ along both the positive and negative $x$-axis.

Comment: Can you flesh that out a bit more? I'm not sure I follow. Ballentine has shown that $\nabla \Psi$ must be continuous (stronger than your requirement) in all cases except for the case of an infinite potential at the given point, thought one finds $\psi = 0$ at such points (except for a delta function potential, where we can have a discontinuity in $\psi'$ and in $\psi$). @MichaelSeifert

Comment: Yeah, now that I've sat down with pen & paper I think I had the case of $0 > \alpha > -1$ in my head and I got confused about it.  Sorry about that!

Comment: No problem at all! Thanks for working it out and clarifying. @MichaelSeifert

Answer (score 1):

The simplest argument is that the probability density
$$
\vert u(r)\vert^2=r^2 \vert R(r)\vert^2
$$
must remain finite at $r=0$.  Note that the right hand side includes an $r^2$ factor since the volume in spherical is $r^2 dr\,\sin\theta d\theta\,d\phi$.

Thus the condition is not on $R(r)$ itself but on $u(r)=rR(r)$.  $u(r)$ itself must be $0$ at the origin by continuity as there is no probability of finding the system in the region $r<0$ by definition of the domain of $r$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If $u(0) = c$ for some nonzero $c$, we still get a finite probability density at $0$, no? And regarding your very last sentence, I'm not sure I follow why that's necessary (it seems to be a completely separate argument from your first one too, unless I'm not following?). What's wrong with a function taking on a nonzero value at the edge of its closed domain?

Comment: Think of the particle-in-a-box.  The wavefunction is $0$ just outside the endpoints because the system cannot be found there ($0$ probability).  By continuity the wavefunction must be $0$ at the endpoints.  It’s the same argument on $u(r)$: by continuity $u(r)$ must be $0$ at the origin.

Comment: If you were to make a graph of $r^2 R(r)^2$, it would have to be $0$ at $r=0$ since the system cannot access the $r<0$ region, *i.e.* $r^2 R^2(r)=0$ for $r<0$.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow or agree with the equivalence. In the 1D particle in a box, we have 0 probability outside the box because the potential is infinite there, not because it’s kinematically not allowed. In this case, $r<0$ is not even defined (it’s not part of the function’s domain), so I’m not sure I can accept the analogy. I’m not trying to be hard-headed here, but am trying to precisely understand the argument.

Comment: From a mathematical perspective there’s no such thing as a kinematical restriction: you just have a differential equation to solve, The differential equation “doesn’t know” the physics, which you inject through the boundary condition.

Comment: The analogy is perfectly valid.  In particular, it allows you to solve the SE for $\ell=0$ in exactly the same way as a 1d-equivalent problem, as you would in ClassMech.

Comment: Again, I'm sorry to perseverate on this but my issue is that $r<0$ is not even defined in this case, so saying $r^2 R^2(r)=0$ for $r<0$ doesn't seem to make sense as justification (since there is no notion of $r<0$? At any rate, I will think about your answer a little bit more. I would also be very grateful if you're able to comment at all on what you think Ballentine might be alluding to, and/or whether his proof works at all despite my protest in the OP.

Comment: The statement “$r<0$ is not even defined” is a physics statement, not a mathematical one: there is nothing mathematically to prevent you from solving for value of $r<0$.  After all, you do solve the SE for $x<0$.  This is precisely where the physics enters: you are forced to exclude $r<0$ *in the solution to your differential equation* on physical grounds

Comment: Ballentine is tight.  Maybe not to the same level as mathematicians but more than enough for this kind of proof.

Comment: "You are forced to exclude $r<0$ in the solution to your differential equation on physical grounds". Again, I don't agree that this is physics -- it's precisely mathematics instead, isn't it? After all, we restrict to $r \geq 0$ when we do a change of variables to spherical coordinates and, so that the change of variables is one-to-one (modulo some details which go above my head), we must require $r \geq 0$. This is what little I recall of my multivariable calculus sadly.

Comment: Can you explain how Ballentine's proof works? In my OP I thought I showed that it wasn't fully tight, insofar as it only requires $u/r$ to have $u(0) = 0$ is $u$ is complex-valued and the integral in his $F$ doesn't vanish? But indeed most cases has $u$ real-valued, so the $\alpha<1$ restriction doesn't apply?

Comment: No.  Your ODE does not know the range of the variables. Just replace $r$ by $\xi$ or any other variable.  What part of math states that the ODE with $\xi$ must be restricted to $\xi>0$?

Comment: Let me give you an alternate example.  Imagine you want to solve SE for a harmonic oscillator with a hard wall on the left. The SE is just an ODE: it's the same as the h.o. whether or not there is a hard wall.  The difference between the usual h.o. and the one with the hard wall is in the BC for the solutions.  With the hard wall you need to exclude all solutions that are not $0$ at the origin.  It's the same idea: an ODE is an ODE.  Solving it not the problem.  The BC - which force some behaviour of the solutions - is the hard part.

Comment: My knowledge of (rigorous) differential equations is limited, but I figure surely it's well-defined to talk about an ODE only being defined on some domain (here, the domain is closed at $0$ but open out at infinity)?

Comment: I hate to bother you given that you've already kindly spent a lot of time helping me with this, but in the end I'm really eager to understand Ballentine's argument in particular. Would you be able to comment on that as that's mostly what my question is after?